# How can we upgrade old GCC 3.4 to GCC 4.1 on Fedora 3?

Tags: linux, gcc, atomic, built-in, operation

How can we upgrade the old GCC from version 3.4 to 4.1(that is from GCC 3.4 to GCC 4.1 or above) on Fedora 3 (version is 2.6.10)?

More information:
We are developing an application which will be running on Fedora 3, but the application needs some atomic built-ins, `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`, `__sync_fetch_and_add`, etc, which are only available on GCC 4.1 or above. SO I think we can either define them or upgrade gcc to new one on Fedora 3, but now we don't know neither.

Comment: You probably need both installed since I am pretty sure the ABI versions of some GCC libraries should have changed between 3.4 and 4.1 and most tools linked against the old version really need it to run. Alternatively, you could probably develop against a more recent GCC version and just deliver it with you compiled binary.

Comment: +1 for @honk's solution: develop against a more recent GCC (just make sure that you have compatible libraries).

Comment: I'd recommend moving this question to [Super User StackExchange](http://superuser.com)

Comment: @honk: first thanks. so as you suggested, the solutions might be : develop on recent GCC version, compiled the project and got the binary   and run this binary app on the Fedora 3? Is that right? What do you mean of "both installed"? Install new GCC and new Fedora?

Comment: @ony : how to do it? If that's more helpful then I would like to

Comment: Why are you working with such archaic versions of everything? The current [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/) release is 17 (and will be 18 in a week, presumably on 2013-01-16). GCC 4.1 is not exactly current either; the latest version is GCC 4.7.1. Since you already have a version of GCC on the machine, you can 'easily' build your own version of GCC 4.x by downloading the source (plus the relevant versions of the source for any prerequisite libraries such as GMP, MPFR, and MPC; the list of prerequisites depends on what you install). You also need a couple of gigabytes of disk space to build.

Comment: @StevePeng: If you can update that system go for it, Fedora3 is antique. What I meant was to develop with some more recent GCC version on some system where it is installed and then to pack up all library dependencies with the final deliverable (I imagine e.g. libstd++,libc, libm) and overwrite the one that gets used e.g. with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`s or `RPATH`s.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'd be curious if gcc-3.4 can even compile a recent gcc. At least for the C++ part gcc-3.4 didn't exactly implement the specs. And just checked, gcc-4.7.2 needs ~8GB, not that much.

Comment: @honk: Classically, GCC could be compiled with a pre-standard C compiler. They're reimplementing GCC in C++ instead of C; that is going to make things harder, but I think that's still 'future', not GCC 4.7.x. For GCC 4.1.x, mentioned in the question, I have no doubt whatsoever that GCC 3.4.5 could be used for the bootstrap build. I think it would be OK for GCC 4.7.x; I'm practically certain it could be used for GCC 4.6.x. The only reason for not using a pre-built GCC is because of the archaic libraries that would be present on Fedora 3; GCC adapts to what it finds when it is built.

Comment: @honk, "_I am pretty sure the ABI versions of some GCC libraries should have changed between 3.4 and 4.1_" No, all versions of GCC since 3.4 are ABI compatible with 3.4 (but not 3.3 or earlier) and the newer libs will work fine for code compiled with 3.4

Comment: "_I'd be curious if gcc-3.4 can even compile a recent gcc_" It varies, there are sometimes problems building a recent GCC with older GCCs, but they're quickly fixed or worked around when found. @JonathanLeffler, GCC has needed an ISO C89 compiler for several years now, since GCC 3.4. Following the C++ move it needs a reasonably good C++98 compiler, and it's been agreed that it must be buildable with G++ 3.4, but not necessarily earlier. See  http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to stick with GCC 3.4 you could use other libraries that provides the same primitives. For example [atomic_ops](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/atomic_ops/) ([atomic_ops @ github](https://github.com/ivmai/libatomic_ops))